# Time lag for generation of electrostatic force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields

Suppose we make a certain point in space charged. Say we impart some negative charge, such that electrostatic condition is maintained.
Then, after the point gets charged will the electric field due to that charge suddenly start existing throughout all of space or will it take some time to propagate further? For example, if a positive test charge is kept at some distance say $r$ away from this point charge, will it feel the attraction force immediately or will there be some time lag before the force is felt by the test charge?
I tried to think of the field as a sphere (due to the radial symmetry) slowly growing in size and eventually attaining a radius of $r$ after which the positive test charge experiences the electrostatic force of attraction. However, this doesn't seem very intuitive to me and I also cannot prove this to be true.
My question is, is there any time lag for the electric field to exist in all points in space after a point is charged (assuming no charge experiences any motion)? If so, why and how can we visualise this? Further, if such a lag exists, is it possible to compute it?

Comment: We can't "make" charge. All charge is balanced. At most we can separate charges, which forms a dipole. The field of that dipole will then propagate at the speed of light. This is what antennas do. So, yes, there is a "time lag" because of the finite speed of light, but now you would have to look closely at the definition and behavior of "time" in special relativity, which is very different from classical mechanics.

Comment: Yep, there is. Go read Purcells Electricity and Magnetism, the chapter on magnetism. He derives the formula for this. However, to do this properly, you need relativity.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I have gone through the book and I do have a rough idea of this concept, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose we make a certain point in space charged. Say we impart some negative charge, such that electrostatic condition is maintained.

As mentioned in the comments, this is not possible according to the continuity equation: $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot \vec j = 0$$

What you can do is produce a dipole by separating two previously co-located charges. However, this inevitably produces a current and thus disrupts the electrostatic condition. You then have a standard dipole field like that from a dipole antenna which radiates outward at $c$ as normal.